# 2D top down collision detection?

Tags: c#, xna

I have been trying to create a collision for a "top down view" like game. I have made a player class and a block class, in my Game1 class I have checked for the collision, don't know if this is a right way, but it's only a test right now. So if I intersect them I don't know what to do next.

This is my Game1.cs

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Collision_Testing {
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Player player = new Player(100, 100);
        Block block = new Block(500, 500);


        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            block.LoadContent(Content);
            player.LoadContent(Content);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();



            block.Update(gameTime);
            player.Update(gameTime);
            base.Update(gameTime);

            if (player.boundingBox.Intersects(block.boundingBox))
            {
                player.playerPos.X -= player.speed;
                player.playerPos.Y -= player.speed;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            player.Draw(spriteBatch);
            block.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    } }
```

This is my Player.cs

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Collision_Testing {
    class Player
    {
        public Vector2 playerPos;
        public Texture2D playerTex;
        public int speed;
        KeyboardState oldState;
        public Rectangle boundingBox;

        public Player(int positionX, int positionY)
        {
            playerPos.X = positionX;
            playerPos.Y = positionY;


            speed = 14;
        }

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            playerTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");
            boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)playerPos.X, (int)playerPos.Y, playerTex.Width, playerTex.Height);
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();

            if(newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                playerPos.X += speed;
            }

            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                playerPos.X -= speed;
            }

            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                playerPos.Y -= speed;
            }

            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            {
                playerPos.Y += speed;
            }


            oldState = newState;
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(playerTex, playerPos, Color.White);
        }
    } }
```

This is my Block.cs

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Collision_Testing {
    class Block
    {
        public Vector2 blockPos;
        public Texture2D blockTex;

        public Rectangle boundingBox;

        public Block(int blockX, int blockY)
        {
            blockPos.X = blockX;
            blockPos.Y = blockY;
        }

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            blockTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("wall");
            boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)blockPos.X, (int)blockPos.Y, blockTex.Width, blockTex.Height);
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(blockTex, blockPos, Color.White);
        }
    } }
```

I think I've done quite a good job for a beginner but don't know what to do next.

Comment: what do you mean you don't know what to do next?  do you not know what you want to do with your objects after you've found that they've collided?

Comment: The player can move freely IN the block, I don't know what to do then. I want it to collide, and then stop against the block.

Comment: What are all those `>`? Get rid of those.

Comment: It looks like someone has edited them out.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Whoops, sorry.. I think someone edited in the `>`'s. I didn't have those in my code at all.

Comment: 2D top-down is the same as 2D side view, you just don't add gravity acceleration to player's momentum. Collision detection stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like speed is a scalar.  so when you intersect with the box,

```
if (player.boundingBox.Intersects(block.boundingBox))
{
    player.playerPos.X -= player.speed;
    player.playerPos.Y -= player.speed;
}
```

you're merely moving the player 14 units to the left, and 14 units up, regardless of where the player was.

It looks like you're intending to subtract the **velocity**.  In order to do that, you first have to declare a velocity

```
public Vector2 playerVelocity;
```

make sure you initialize `playerVelocity` in your constructor.

and then you should modify the velocity instead of the position when measuring input

```
if(newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{
    playerVelocity.X = speed;
}
else if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
{
    playerVelocity.X  = -speed;
}
else
{
    playerVelocity.X = 0;
}
...


playerPos += playerVelocity;

// i believe you can just add Vectors in XNA like this
// but if it makes you feel better you can do playerPos.X += playerVelocity.X
```

and then you can reverse your player's position when you collide

```
if (player.boundingBox.Intersects(block.boundingBox))
{
    player.playerPos -= player.playerVelocity;
}
```

Comment: Oh god this is seriously making me lag, when I pressed right my character just FLEW off the map, I know what I did wrong (I had += and -= instead of =) But that was hilarious for me. Altough, theres a little problem, my character doesn't stop moving right now. Altough this solution works, it doesn't work the way I want to!

Comment: @Stepepper Than set your `playerVelocity` to 0 if you're not pressing a button.  I've edited my post

Comment: It uh.. it seems like the bounding boxes are wrong? The player doesn't collide although they do on screen.

Comment: Okay I fixed that, now it goes a little bit inside of the block before stopping when I press the key, when I release the key it goes back to normal, any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If your character doesn't stop moving I think you miss something like this:

```
if (newState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up) && newState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Down) &&
    newState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left) && newState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right))
{
   playerVelocity = Vector2.Zero;
}
```